# After upgrading to JasperReports 4.7.0, the editor does not show the staticText value or textField value. No error on compile

Tags: migration, jasper-reports

We are migrating our reports from *JasperReports / iReport* from version *3.0* to *4.7.0*. I installed *iReport 4.7.0* and was also able to execute most of the existing reports without any issue.

With few reports, in the Editor of the *iReport*, the ***textField / staticText*** text box is empty. The values should be applied during runtime but its empty then also. Thus when clicked on **Preview** button, empty report is generated.

Database connection is also set correctly.

When checked their corresponding properties, the ***textField*** expression / Text value is correctly assigned (Example : `$F{balance}`).

I am new with JasperReports and totally not sure how to address this issue. Any insights would be really helpful.

Comment: Your best bet is to attach one of the problematic reports to your queston, so everyone can take a look.

Comment: Unfortunately, I will unable to upload the propriety page. Also, as a new user, I am unable to upload any files.In the report, I can see all the fields/parameters on the Left hand side Property Inspector. But on the report, just the plain text boxes. When executed, there is no content shown in the report. With version 3.0 I can run the same report successfully but not on 4.70. There is no logs/compile/runtime error also. Not sure how to troubleshoot this issue,

Comment: JasperReports, before being compiled are essentially a text file with xml in it. I was just asking you to edit the body of your question to include that xml. Unfortunately with out an example to reproduce the same problem, it is hard to help.

Comment: Thank you so much for ur help :) i have added a snapshot of the code... Its originally a very huge file .. please let me know ur thoughts.. Thanks

Comment: And in iReport you are sure you are running it against the database and do not accidentally have it set to use an empty datasource (drop down next to the connection icon on the toolbar)? Do you get any errors when you click preview? If not, I would try creating a new report in iReport, recreating one that is not working, just to see if you have the same problem.

Comment: it is connected to an actual DB connection... With a new report, all works correctly... other reports executed correctly too... With this report also there is no runtime error or compile time error...It will be a huge task to reconstruct this report from scratch... thus, i was wondering if i can fix any settings within IReport or some tweaking that could fix the issue...

Comment: Well I know you have it configured that way, but iReport has an option to use the connection or to use an Empty data source when previewing. I am perplexed at this point, and reccomend trying to recreate the reports in iReport (not copy pasting, but actually redoing it).

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting a different font on all the text fields. It may only appear that they are empty, but  the font you were using is not installed.